# Sharing Business and Personal Accounts on Google Chrome with Sync Enabled

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-workspace

I work remotely for a company that requires I use my own computer. Fine. 
Since they use GSuite, they recommend Chrome for everyone. It's a small company, and lax about policy. So there's no computer policy document that I'm aware of. And yes, I would rather have the company provide a laptop to use. They refused. Getting another job is easier said than done, so I was stuck.

As a practice, I usually have two instances of Chrome. One where I'm logged in under my personal account, and another instance where I'm logged in under my business account. OK, better than doing everything on the business account, but still easy to forget ( I also have separate virtual desktops for personal/business to make it easier ).

I found out BY DEFAULT syncing was turned on for my business account. When I looked at some of the things that got synced, I got a little nervous ( bank account password, password manager, etc). So occasionally I slipped up and did some personal stuff on the business account desktop / chrome account ( nothing weird, checked bank balance, answered some personal emails, etc)

So a couple of questions here:
1) I assume ( uh-oh ) that syncing for the business account doesn't sync the personal account as well. But how do I know?
2) For the work account stuff that is synced, can the admin log in as me, then see all the information that has been synced under the business account? For example, if a username/password combo was synced, would they then be able to log into that account as me?
3) I use Google Drive on the laptop with my personal account. I assume it's isolated from Google Drive on the business account?

I think the safest thing is NOT to use Chrome on the business side. But that's going forward. For the past six months, I've been using Chrome, unaware of the fact that it's syncing something to the business. I'm trying to know what it's done and how accessible that information is. IF there's something I could read that would tell me, a link would be great! I googled for some time, and can't find the level of detail I need to know what's going on here.

Comment: To achieve better separation use Chrome for their business (G-Suite) and Edge for your self and your stuff. This separates by browser and will be safer for you.

Comment: Edge even has a Chromium build now that's like Chrome. Or use different use accounts.

Comment: I'd assume there's some privacy protections for user content in gsuite. Just having gsuite doesn't mean the admins can sign in as you. But, writing this out I cannot shake the feeling I've seen this exact question, and recently. Did you ask this same question perhaps a month ago? What you should do is change all of your passwords. Period. That's the only and best course of action.

Comment: Thanks - definitely agree going forward two separate browsers are the way to go, and password changes across the board are required. 

The question I'm left with is what exactly did he have access to for six months. In that time, who knows what he could have accessed and copied. And yes, there is reason to be concerned with this individual, since he told me he "knew" some remote employees weren't working even though they were online.

Answer (score 0):

The only and correct course of action is to change your account passwords.

Even if Google isolates content within gsuite to protect user credentials, you cannot trust anyone other than yourself to protect your own privacy and security.

So change your passwords and you'll have the greatest chance of being just fine.